# Check HTTP Referer ONLY if url contains specific query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've searched broad and wide for an answer to this, but without any luck.
I would like to know if it's possible (either through PHP or .htaccess) to check if the HTTP referer is coming from my own domain, **ONLY** if the URL which the visitor is attempting to visit, contains a specific query string.

An example:
For a website which offers downloads it's ideal to not let other websites "link directly to the download link of a file", and therefore try to block it.

A direct download link could be as such: `www.mysite.com/?download=123` where the query of `?download=123` initiates the file download.

However, blocking all HTTP refereres is not ideal and should only happen with regards to downloads; or more specific, if the url contains the string `?download=`

I know the caveats of relying on HTTP referer as it can easily be spoofed, but 100% security is not the goal in this case.

---

EDIT 1:

As I didn't realize the extent of my initial question here comes some more information:

I'm currently using Wordpress, and with it I have a download-managing plugin called Delightful Downloads. The plugin works the way, that on load/initiation of the page it creates specific download links matching the files through php. Such a download link can look like the follow: `www.mysite.com/?download=123` . As pointed out these links are created during initiation/load and are also placed on the first page of the website. Because the download-link doesn't end on `.jpg` or alike, blocking access to these extensions based on HTTP referer doesn't work (at least when I tried).

This "flow of download" has also caused that i can't find a "download initiatior/call/function" since it's activated when visiting the page including the query string.

The problem lies in the fact that visitors, or other websites, can link directly to the link containing the query string, resulting in a "direct download". This is troublesome as the people downloading should agree to a set of "terms of use" before being able to download.

Comment: You can achieve this with `.htaccess`. Look into url rewriting, there are enough guides in the internet.

Comment: It can be spoofed and a legitimate user's browser/software may not send it. But yes you can check it..

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I've honestly tried searching with every possible phrase which i thought matched these terms, but I haven't been able to find any topic showing/discussing .. Guess i might be blind or bad at using google :)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Referer agents can be easily spoofed by anyone. As mentioned by Chris85. What I'm noticing a lot more of is that browser agents now typically do not provide referrer contents at all, they're ,much more often just empty strings.

If you're trying to track a user is visiting a page on your site from another page *on your site* you can record relevant information in PHP `$_SESSION` data, so on page 1, set a session with a page address (*not* `PHP_SELF`) and possibly some form of timestamp, and then compare these values on the destination page.

### page 1 (from)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['visitTime'] = time();
$_SESSION['visitAddress'] = __FILE__ //or some othe random yet checkable data
```

### page 2 (to)

```
 session_start();
 //example checking criteria only
 if($_SESSION['visitTime'] > (time() - 300) 
    && !empty($_SESSION['visitAddress'])){
     //do stuff, as another page on your site has been visited
     // by this user within the last 5 minutes. 
 }
```

Reading your question it seems more like you're trying to prevent hotlinking, and most servers now do provide various facilities for doing this automatically. using `$_SESSION`s will achieve this if you simply use a variation on my example above.

[`.Htaccess` prevent hotlinking](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/)  (image specific but can be adapted for other file types)

[(Slghtly) broader details for `.htaccess` file hotlink prevention](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644230/prevent-hotlinking-with-a-htaccess-file)

Comment: Actually just thought that the last link you provided was my solution, but then i realized that it sadly doesn't provide the solution of blocking hotlinking to url with a specific query string.  I've actually already tried the session & time() solution, however the download links are created (by plugin) when the page is loaded and is also placed at the 1st page. This means that i cant block access to this link based on the time, as they are already loaded during the initiation in php.

Comment: Well then you can use some form of CSRF key, generate a key on your site, that is used (Rather like a Session id is used) and compare, simply set a value in a session variable (such as time, whatever) and then check this value when downloading, if the value (time) is empty or over an hour ago you can assume that the link is direct or they're using a cached link (ie not new) .

Comment: @Chri.s given the details you've outlined in your comment I think it may help us if you edit and added a broader explanation of your situation to your question. Cheers. I would like more details about your "plugin" and about the paths/routes that people currently take to your download, and how you want to filter these. Cheers

Comment: I'll give you an update in a second and hopefully that will make some more sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

htaccess solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com/.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^download=([0-9]+)$
# redirect to another page
# ? at the end creates new query string and discards the old
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Besides that i would like the RewriteRule to just remove the query string/redirect to my frontpage (**due to my lacking information**) this is actually the solution i was looking for :)

Comment: Oh and allow for blank/unset referers, as these are blocked otherwise

Comment: I've changed my answer to make it a redirect and make blak referrer possible

Comment: For some reason this blocks the page even when trying to access it from my own domain / redirected from own domain.

Comment: It would appear that my website dóesn't set a referer.. No idea why though. https://www.whatismyreferer.com/ gives a "no referer / hidden" response, and same goes for a similar website. It would seem that the "blank referer" rewritecondition doesn't catch this?

Comment: I have literally NO idea what's going on.. With the above conditions i can no longer directly access the download link from the URL (even when i'm trying to access it from my own site), however i can (seemingly) download it when clicking a link on my page.. Which in turn just redirects to the download url?

Comment: Aha, after gathering some more information it would seem that entering a URL manually into the "adress bar" results in an "empty" referer. Now it works the way that clicking a link on the page results in a succesful download. However, given that the 'blank' rewritecond apparently isn't working correctly (at least on my PC), it will probably also block visitors who have turned their referer off?